# Computing which side of a line a point is

Tags: geometry

I asked [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779577/computing-which-side-of-a-line-a-point-is):
[image]

$AB$ is the line, $C$ is the point.

In the accepted answer of the above question, if the difference in equation is $0$, then points are collinear, so in the above image, it proves it correct as theta is same, so far so good.

Then in the image below, $C$ lies on right of line :

[image]

the fi angle is less than theta so the difference is positive. So in my program if I take $> 0$ as condition for the point on right, then the difference should always be greater than $0$ if point is on right.

But my next figure shows that the even if the point is on right of the line, the difference can be negative :

[image]

In figure 3, even though the point is on right of the line, fi is greater than theta, so the diffrence is negative.

In accepted answer, if I take positive difference for point on right side, then the above case will give wrong results.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Rather complicated, that. Do you know the [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) for computing a *directed* point-line distance? Alternatively, if your line segment is represented by its two endpoints, you could use the determinantal formula for the *signed* area of a triangle.

Comment: In the figure 2, your assumption of the angle $\phi$ is wrong. You should always take the angle the line makes with the x-axis in the anti-clockwise direction. Hence $\phi$ in that case would be 'obtuse angle' and hence the difference would turn out to be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J.M. has it -- compute the [signed determinant area](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheAreaOfATriangleUsingADeterminant/) of the triangle ABC

- If it's zero, the points are colinear
- If it's +ve then C is on one side of the line (depending on which way you write down the
  determinant...)
- If it's -ve then C is on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

according to figure 2, instead of checking:
$$
\frac {Bx-Ax}{By-Ay} - \frac {Cx-Ax}{Cy-Ay}
$$

You should check the angle from +ve x-axis (phi you are taking is measured from -ve x-axis):
$$
\tan^{-1}( \frac {Ay-By}{Ax-Bx}) < abs (\tan^{-1}(\frac{Cy-Ay}{Cx-Ay}))
$$
this will be true for both figures 2 and 3 and all points on the right side.

and the angle of CA w.r.t +ve x-axis would be less than angle of BA w.r.t. +ve x-axis, if C lies on the left hand side of the line.